# Exp:resso Store: Min/Max Order Quantity

Tags: expresso-store

I am using Exp:resso Store to manage a shop that needs the ability to set a minimum number of products purchased, and a maximum. For instance, we may require that 4 spoons be purchased, but no more than 24. Any number between those is valid since the spoons do not come in packages of 4.

At first glance, the Store custom field allows us to set a total quantity in stock (next to the "Limit Stock" checkbox), and to set a "Min Order Quantity."

If I set "Min Order Quantity" to 4, the cart will still allow me to add a single product.

Question #1: Why is that?

Question #2: While looking at this, I found several references to "max_order_qty" in the code for the shipping module. Is there a way to apply this to a specific product in the cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't sound right - can you please email support@exp-resso.com with CP login details so that we may investigate this issue for you.

Comment: Looks like it was only an issue in my local dev environment. Weird.